# mcp2221 i2c CLOCK down after ACK

Tags: i2c, microchip

I am trying to control an Analog Devices programming resistor AD5254 by a USB to I2C master device from MicroChip MCP2221. The problem I am facing is that each time MCP2221 is waiting for ACK from AD5254, the SCL clock de-assert which i think affect the AD5254 to not be configured properly. 
This is what happens : 
1. Using MicroChip I2C/SMbus Terminal I am sending the following  :
[image]
2. observing SDA/SCL using a scope + I2C protocol analyzer I can see the address+data are ok but after each Ack SCL line drops :
[image]
3. I know that the address+data is correct because I am using Analog Devices Evaluation board for reference, and when connecting their SDP-B controller board (UG-277) to the Evaluation (UG-236) the SDA/SCL signals are correct : 
[image]

Anyone know why SCL drops after each ACK ?

Comment: Do you have write protect enabled hence it only stores the volatile value. SCL probably drops after an ACK because it can.

Comment: The data looks fine except something is [stretching the clock](https://www.i2c-bus.org/i2c-primer/clock-generation-stretching-arbitration/)

Comment: thanks Andy, that was it ! you helped finish couple of days debug !